# Phonegap wp8.1 app pushes body out of CordovaView

Tags: cordova, extjs, windows-phone-8.1, sencha-touch

I am developing an app using phonegap 3.X + sencha touch 2.3.1

When the softkeyboard is shown (tap to foucus an input/textarea), the body moves up. But when I hide the softkeyboard, the body didn't restore to normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any of your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only occurs if you hide the status bar (shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"), 
I have a workaround for this issue,
modify this file \platforms\wp8\MainPage.xaml ,

change :

```
<my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Margin="0,0,0,0"  
               x:Name="CordovaView" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

to:

```
<my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Margin="1,0,0,0"  
               x:Name="CordovaView" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```